# In order to create this CDN profile, please ensure that Microsoft.CDN is listed as a registered Resource Provider in your Azure subscription

Tags: azure

I am trying to create a front door CDN profile, but I get the following error:

```
In order to create this CDN profile, please ensure that Microsoft.CDN is listed as a registered Resource Provider in your Azure subscription
```

[image]

But I see my cdn is registered. But i do still get the error.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, `Microsoft.Cdn` was already registered. What I did is I selected `Microsoft.Cdn` and clicked on **Re-register**. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check and confirm if the Microsoft.CDN resource provider is indeed registered for your subscription by running the below PS cmdlet.

```
Connect-AzAccount
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'

# PS cmdlet to check if the provider is registered
Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.CDN

# If it is not registered, Run the below command to register the Resource Provider
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.CDN
```